# Get value from a json in c#

Tags: c#, json, amadeus

I am trying to get value from a bigger json ,But i am nearly lost completely in implementing it.Kindly guide me.I have given my json string and c# code i have tried.

c# Code:

```
string cityname = "";
            string strCity = File.ReadAllText("E:/HotelResult.txt");
            dynamic city = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strCity);
            foreach (var hotel in city)
            {
               
                    cityname = hotel.type;
                
            }
```

Hotel.Result(Json):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "hotel-offers",
      "hotel": {
        "type": "hotel",
        "hotelId": "ALNYC647",
        "chainCode": "AL",
        "dupeId": "501447323",
        "name": "Aloft Manhattan Downtown - Financial District",
        "rating": "4",
        "cityCode": "NYC",
        "latitude": 40.71041,
        "longitude": -74.00666,
        "hotelDistance": {
          "distance": 0.4,
          "distanceUnit": "KM"
        },
        "address": {
          "lines": [
            "49 53 ANN STREET"
          ],
          "postalCode": "10038",
          "cityName": "NEW YORK",
          "countryCode": "US",
          "stateCode": "NY"
        },
        "contact": {
          "phone": "+1 212 513-0003",
          "fax": "+1 212 513-0004",
          "email": "info@aloftmanhattandowntown.com"
        },
        "description": {
          "lang": "en",
          "text": "Celebrate your style at Aloft Manhattan Downtown - Financial District, a hip new hotel where you'll be close to corporate headquarters, Wall Street and the World Trade Center. We offer easy-breezy access to Big Apple hotspots via nearby subway lines. Meet & mingle with friends at our w xyz(SM) bar, grab a sweet, savory or healthy snack from re:fuel by Aloft(SM), our 24/7 pantry or play in our re:mix(SM) lounge. Plus, you can always stay connected with free hotel-wide wired and wireless High Speed Internet Access! Breeze into one of our Aloft rooms, featuring our ultra-comfortable signature bed, walk-in shower, custom amenities by Bliss® Spa and more."
        },
        "amenities": [
          "SPA",
          "SERV_DOGS_ALWD",
          "ACC_TOILETS",
          "HANDRAIL_BTHRM",
          "24_HOUR_FRONT_DESK",
          "CAR_RENTAL",
          "EXPRESS_CHECK_IN",
          "LOUNGE",
          "ICE_MACHINES",
          "FLORIST",
          "TRAVEL_AGENCY",
          "CONCIERGE",
          "SAFE_DEP_BOX",
          "LAUNDRY_SVC",
          "ATM/CASH_MACHINE",
          "EXPRESS_CHECK_OUT",
          "WEDDING_SERVICES",
          "GYM",
          "RESTAURANT",
          "HI_INTERNET",
          "FREE_INTERNET",
          "WIRELESS_CONNECTIVITY",
          "ELEVATOR",
          "PETS_ALLOWED",
          "PHOTOCOPIER",
          "PRINTER",
          "BUSINESS_CENTER",
          "MEETING_FACILITIES",
          "INTERNET-HI_SPEED_IN_RM",
          "WI-FI_IN_ROOM",
          "NONSMOKING_RMS",
          "FREE_LOCAL_CALLS",
          "TEA/COFFEE_MK_FACILITIES",
          "ALARM_CLOCK",
          "AIR_CONDITIONING",
          "SAFE",
          "IRON/IRON_BOARD",
          "CRIBS_AVAILABLE",
          "TELEVISION",
          "HAIR_DRYER",
          "VOICEMAIL_IN_ROOM",
          "PHONE-DIR_DIAL",
          "CORDLESS_PHONE",
          "REFRIGERATOR",
          "OUTLET_ADAPTERS",
          "CABLE_TELEVISION",
          "FITNESS_CENTER"
        ]
      },
      "available": true,
      "offers": [
        {
          "id": "LBRB9R0B0X",
          "checkInDate": "2020-09-13",
          "checkOutDate": "2020-09-14",
          "rateCode": "S9R",
          "rateFamilyEstimated": {
            "code": "SRS",
            "type": "C"
          },
          "room": {
            "type": "XMI",
            "typeEstimated": {
              "beds": 1,
              "bedType": "QUEEN"
            },
            "description": {
              "lang": "EN",
              "text": "Marriott Senior Discount, includes 62 years and older valid ID \nSleeps 2, Fast & free WiFi throughout the hotel\n, 1 Queen, 200sqft/18sqm-220sqft/20sqm, Wireles"
            }
          },
          "guests": {
            "adults": 1
          },
          "price": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "base": "127.00",
            "total": "149.25",
            "variations": {
              "average": {
                "base": "127.00"
              },
              "changes": [
                {
                  "startDate": "2020-09-13",
                  "endDate": "2020-09-14",
                  "base": "127.00"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "policies": {
            "paymentType": "guarantee",
            "cancellation": {
              "deadline": "2020-09-13T09:29:00+05:30"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "self": "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel?hotelId=ALNYC647"
    },
    {
      "type": "hotel-offers",
      "hotel": {
        "type": "hotel",
        "hotelId": "HXNYC432",
        "chainCode": "HX",
        "dupeId": "700051862",
        "name": "HAMPTON INN MANHATTAN-DOWNTOWN-FINANCIAL",
        "rating": "2",
        "cityCode": "NYC",
        "latitude": 40.70312,
        "longitude": -74.01228,
        "hotelDistance": {
          "distance": 1.3,
          "distanceUnit": "KM"
        },
        "address": {
          "lines": [
            "32 PEARL ST"
          ],
          "postalCode": "10004",
          "cityName": "NEW YORK",
          "countryCode": "US",
          "stateCode": "NY"
        },
        "contact": {
          "phone": "1-212-480-3500",
          "fax": "1-212-480-3700"
        },
        "amenities": [
          "BUSINESS_CENTER",
          "ADAPTED_PHONES",
          "WIDE_ENTRANCE",
          "WIDE_CORRIDORS",
          "FIRST_AID_STAF",
          "INT_ROOM_ENTRY",
          "EMERG_LIGHTING",
          "FIRE_DETECTORS",
          "EXTINGUISHERS",
          "FIRE_SAFETY",
          "RESTRIC_RM_ACC",
          "SMOKE_DETECTOR",
          "SPRINKLERS",
          "LAUNDRY_SVC",
          "PARKING",
          "PETS_ALLOWED",
          "SAFE_DEP_BOX",
          "AIR_CONDITIONING",
          "HAIR_DRYER",
          "MOVIE_CHANNELS",
          "NONSMOKING_RMS",
          "PC_HOOKUP_INRM",
          "TELEVISION",
          "FITNESS_CENTER"
        ],
        "media": [
          {
            "uri": "http://uat.multimediarepository.testing.amadeus.com/cmr/retrieve/hotel/9E95CFEC3B6F4C459EDC0F267159B799",
            "category": "EXTERIOR"
          }
        ]
      },
      "available": true,
      "offers": [
        {
          "id": "Y0IT2BLO9V",
          "checkInDate": "2020-09-13",
          "checkOutDate": "2020-09-14",
          "rateCode": "RAC",
          "rateFamilyEstimated": {
            "code": "AAA",
            "type": "C"
          },
          "commission": {
            "percentage": "10.00"
          },
          "boardType": "BREAKFAST",
          "room": {
            "type": "C1Q",
            "typeEstimated": {
              "category": "ACCESSIBLE_ROOM",
              "beds": 1,
              "bedType": "QUEEN"
            },
            "description": {
              "lang": "EN",
              "text": "AAA RATE\n1 QUEEN ACCESSIBLE ROLL IN SHOWER NONSMOKING\nHDTV/WORK AREA"
            }
          },
          "guests": {
            "adults": 1
          },
          "price": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "base": "594.15",
            "total": "685.29",
            "variations": {
              "average": {
                "base": "594.15"
              },
              "changes": [
                {
                  "startDate": "2020-09-13",
                  "endDate": "2020-09-14",
                  "base": "594.15"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "policies": {
            "paymentType": "guarantee",
            "cancellation": {
              "deadline": "2020-09-10T09:30:00+05:30"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "self": "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel?hotelId=HXNYC432"
    },
    {
      "type": "hotel-offers",
      "hotel": {
        "type": "hotel",
        "hotelId": "BWNYC133",
        "chainCode": "BW",
        "dupeId": "700101379",
        "name": "Best Western Bowery Hanbee Hotel",
        "rating": "2",
        "cityCode": "NYC",
        "latitude": 40.7184,
        "longitude": -73.99518,
        "hotelDistance": {
          "distance": 1.0,
          "distanceUnit": "KM"
        },
        "address": {
          "lines": [
            "231 GRAND STREET"
          ],
          "postalCode": "10013",
          "cityName": "NEW YORK CITY",
          "countryCode": "US",
          "stateCode": "NY"
        },
        "contact": {
          "phone": "+1 212 9251177",
          "fax": "+1 212 9255533",
          "email": "33133@hotel.bestwestern.com"
        },
        "description": {
          "lang": "en",
          "text": "Stay at this 100% non-smoking New York City, New York hotel located next to the subway and key local attractions such as Canal Street, Chinatown and Little Italy. Welcome to the Best Western Bowery Hanbee Hotel, where guests will find exceptional customer service and accommodations at an affordable rate. This New York City hotel features well-appointed guest rooms and suites, each offering cable satellite television with free HBO® and free wireless high-speed Internet access. Guests staying at this 100% non-smoking hotel will enjoy a complimentary hot breakfast buffet each morning before heading out to sightsee. Additional amenities include an exercise facility and a full-service business center. The Best Western Bowery Hanbee Hotel is ideally located less than one mile from many New York attractions including Chinatown, Little Italy, the Wall Street financial district and the World Trade Center Memorial. Hotel guests will enjoy an afternoon of shopping on 5th Avenue or visiting key sights such as Ellis Island, the Statue of Liberty, the Empire State Building and Times Square. Corporate travelers will appreciate being a half mile from the New York Stock Exchange, the Federal Reserve Bank, JP Morgan and American Express®. This New York hotel is also ideal for viewing several annual events including the Macy's Thanksgiving Day Parade®, the Chinese New Year and the Tribeca Film Festival. The friendly, helpful staff at the Best Western Bowery Hanbee Hotel is ready to ensure a fun-filled memorable stay in New York, New York. Make a reservation today and save! Enjoy your stay!"
        },
        "amenities": [
          "24_HOUR_FRONT_DESK",
          "GYM",
          "HI_INTERNET",
          "ELEVATOR",
          "ICE_MACHINES",
          "SPRINKLERS",
          "FIRE_DETECTORS",
          "FEMA_FIRE_SAFETY_COMPLIANT",
          "SMOKE_DETECTOR",
          "EMERG_LIGHTING",
          "HANDICAP_FAC",
          "BUSINESS_CENTER",
          "FREE_LOCAL_CALLS",
          "PHONE-DIR_DIAL",
          "INTERNET-HI_SPEED_IN_RM",
          "HAIR_DRYER",
          "AIR_CONDITIONING",
          "CABLE_TELEVISION",
          "VOICEMAIL_IN_ROOM",
          "SAFE",
          "WAKEUP_SERVICE",
          "ALARM_CLOCK",
          "TEA/COFFEE_MK_FACILITIES",
          "CRIBS_AVAILABLE"
        ],
        "media": [
          {
            "uri": "http://uat.multimediarepository.testing.amadeus.com/cmr/retrieve/hotel/A15115741A8747538ECDBB2AA76B7DE9",
            "category": "EXTERIOR"
          }
        ]
      },
      "available": true,
      "offers": [
        {
          "id": "MLX8YR77R7",
          "checkInDate": "2020-09-13",
          "checkOutDate": "2020-09-14",
          "rateCode": "SRS",
          "rateFamilyEstimated": {
            "code": "SRS",
            "type": "C"
          },
          "commission": {
            "percentage": "10"
          },
          "boardType": "BREAKFAST",
          "room": {
            "type": "A1Q",
            "typeEstimated": {
              "category": "ACCESSIBLE_ROOM",
              "beds": 1,
              "bedType": "QUEEN"
            },
            "description": {
              "lang": "EN",
              "text": "SENIOR RATE*CITIZENS 55YRS PLUS OR AARP ID\n1 QUEEN BED,MOBILITY ACC,COMMASSIST,ROLL SHWR,\nNSMK,CONTINENTAL BREAKFAST"
            }
          },
          "guests": {
            "adults": 1
          },
          "price": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "base": "242.10",
            "total": "281.31",
            "variations": {
              "average": {
                "base": "242.10"
              },
              "changes": [
                {
                  "startDate": "2020-09-13",
                  "endDate": "2020-09-14",
                  "base": "242.10"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "policies": {
            "paymentType": "guarantee",
            "cancellation": {
              "deadline": "2020-09-11T09:30:00+05:30"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "self": "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel?hotelId=BWNYC133"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "links": {
      "next": "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers?cityCode=NYC&page[offset]=BF2MJFOB9ASN_100"
    }
  }
}
```

Now i need to acess the name,description and contact from the json .Kindly help i am struck with this.The pointer doesnt go inside the hotel child.

Comment: If you navigate to https://app.quicktype.io/ you can easily convert your json into C# classes, so you can easily get your data with little effort!
Your json can be converterted as this one: https://app.quicktype.io?share=hjL51EWajmfaVqATCl3x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an example by only extracting a portion of your code

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                    
public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        string cityname = "";
        string json = "{\"data\": [{\"type\": \"hotel-offers\",\"hotel\": {\"type\": \"hotel\",\"hotelId\": \"ALNYC647\",\"chainCode\": \"AL\",\"dupeId\": \"501447323\",\"name\": \"Aloft Manhattan Downtown - Financial District\",\"rating\": \"4\",\"cityCode\": \"NYC\",\"latitude\": 40.71041,\"longitude\": -74.00666,\"hotelDistance\": {\"distance\": 0.4,\"distanceUnit\": \"KM\"}}}]}";
        dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        cityname = parsedJson.data[0].hotel.name;
        Console.WriteLine(cityname);
    }
}
```

while copying the dynamic and cityname thing would solve your problem. You should pay attention to some other problems you might have with your model.

1 - If there were more than one row in the data of your json you would be getting only the last cityname. And you would be losing all the other ones

2 - It is better as pointed out in your comments by @Marco to actually map that json

Answer (score 0):

I use JObject for json,it works like this:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("E:/HotelResult.txt");
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
string name = (string)o["data"]["name"];
string contactPhone = (string)o["data"]["contact"]["phone"];
```

I hope I could help you

Comment: I get an error:'Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "name". Int32 array index expected.'

Comment: Your answer does not work because data is an array of objects